# Cann't give localhot as domain name in 'Home Page URL' field during project creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, yahoo-api, import-contacts

I want to retrieve Yahoo contacts, so for this I'm try to create project for getting app key in `Yahoo Contact API` page.
but facing following problem.

> Cannot give localhost as domain name in 'Home Page URL' field during project creation for 'Yahoo Contact API'(it isn't error message,this field need valid domain name instead of localhost)

I have googled everything but could find any solution.

Following is project creation URL.you need login to view this page

https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/dashboard/createKey.html

http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Is the `Cann't` and `localhot` misspelled in your question or in the error message?

Comment: misspelled.I'm going to correct them

Comment: If Yahoo won't accept `localhost`, there's no way you can force them to.  However, @MotoSV's answer is a really good workaround, if you remember to do it on every machine that will be testing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a similar error I got when signing up for a Twitter app key. You could try putting in a proper domain name, any will do, and then modify your hosts file in windows to map that domain name to 127.0.0.1.